# CSS Hover Transition

Tags: html, css, webkit, css-transitions, transition

I am trying to create the css transition similar to the navbar of [this.](http://goshoppe.co.in/index.php?route=common/home)

I have tried following code but it didn't work.

```
        .navbar-default .navbar-nav li a{
  /*  color: #fff; */
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-left: 24px;
    padding-right: 24px;
    position: relative;
  }

  .navbar-default .navbar-nav li a:before{
    background-color: #c83a3a;
    height: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    width: 0;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    z-index: -1;
  }

  .navbar-default .navbar-nav li:hover a:before{
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  }
```

My Current Website is [here](http://ec2-54-169-208-115.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/magento/index.php/)
This does not work for top level menu bar and works for rest of all

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav li a{
  /*  color: #fff; */
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-left: 24px;
    padding-right: 24px;
    position: relative; /* change */
  }

  /*.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a:hover
  {
    background-color: #c83a3a;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  }*/

  .navbar-default .navbar-nav li a:before{
    background-color: #c83a3a;
    height: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    width: 0;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    z-index: -1;
  }

  /* change */
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav li:hover a:before{
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  }
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/p3aqno7j/

Comment: I have tried to put this code but the color of dropdown menu changes instead of the parent.... You can check My site live at http://ec2-54-169-208-115.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/magento/index.php/

Comment: @VashikaranSpecialist Can u make a fiddle with your menu code?